# Quick checkup on python list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I currently generate lists using following expression (T and no_jobs are integers):

```
for i in xrange(no_jobs):
    row = row + T * [i]
```

The first thing I came up with for converting it into a list comprehension statement was:

```
[T*[i] for i in xrange(no_jobs)]
```

But this obviously creates a nested list which is not what I'm looking for. All my other ideas seems a litle clunky so if anyone has a pythonic and elegant way of creating these types of lists I would be gratefull.

Comment: for i in range(no_jobs): for x in range(T):
    row.append(i)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nested loops.

```
[i for i in xrange(no_jobs) for x in xrange(T)]
```

Answer (score 0):

> But this obviously creates a nested list which is not what I'm looking for.

So just flatten the result. List addition is concatenation, so we can put all the lists together by 'summing' them (with an empty list as an "accumulator").

```
sum((T*[i] for i in xrange(no_jobs)), [])
```

Comment: -1 It doesn't do what you say it does, and it doesn't work. You need `sum((T*[i] for i in xrange(no_jobs)), [])`

Comment: @JohnMachin Edited. I don't know how I indicated the need for an accumulator parameter and then left it out. And yes, `sum` does not use `*args`.